# CSS selector based on parent and child nodes?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, css-selectors

Is there a way I can express the following as a single CSS selector? (Or will I have to find some other way to do this besides using a CSS selector until Level 4 is a reality? See: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject)

I want …

- the **only** div (of unknown class)
- that has a div grandchild titled "foo"
- and that has a grandparent div with class "bar baz"

There are two divs on the page that have a grandchild titled "foo". I want to match only the one that also has a grandparent div with the class "bar baz".

This is for use with Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: wait for css 4 or use js

Comment: This is exactly the case for xpath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible with a single CSS selector.

The criterion "has a grandparent div" requires the subject selector introduced in Selectors level 4, which would result in the following selector (assuming "titled" means "has a `title` attribute equal to"):

```
div.bar.baz > * > !div > * > div[title="foo"]
```

And there isn't a way to select the nth or only occurrence of an element **in an entire page**, so your first criterion can never be satisfied using a CSS selector. Not to mention the above won't work anyway since currently there isn't any browser that implements Selectors 4.

You're probably better off using DOM traversal or XPath instead. The XPath expression I'm thinking of is much more complicated, but it *can* find the only occurrence of an element in an entire page (if I have it correct that is... you may have to test it on your own page):

```
(
  //div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' bar ') and contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' baz ')]
    /*
      /div[child::*/child::div[@title="foo"]]
)[1][last()]
```

If you're looking for an exact match on the `class` attribute for the grandparent, use this XPath instead (again untested):

```
(
  //div[@class="bar baz"]
    /*
      /div[child::*/child::div[@title="foo"]]
)[1][last()]
```

Comment: "Otherwise, this isn't possible with a CSS selector currently." sorry i messed up the downvote but now it's either +1 either -1 & i really doubt the css before the otherwise is working

Comment: @mikakun: Of course it doesn't work. Maybe I should state that explicitly. You can also undo your downvote without upvoting by clicking the down arrow again - it behaves like a toggle button in that sense. I'll also add an XPath alternative in case the OP is able to use it.

Comment: indeed; but what the point of providing an answer that doesn't work ?

Comment: @mikakun: The OP did mention Selectors 4 so I thought I'd provide a theoretical example. That said, I've edited my answer.

Comment: @BoltClock: sorry if this is a silly question but are the newlines in the xpaths significant? Do /* and */ somehow mark the "subject" of the xpath?

Comment: @user1011471: They're not significant; they're just plain whitespace for readability. `/*` means "any element type as child", and `div[child::*/child::div[...]]` means "a `div` with a `div` grandchild"; the left `div` outside of the square brackets is the so-called subject of the XPath.

Comment: @BoltClock: Huzzah -- that worked! Thanks! (I also sent the developer a request to  specify ids for all interesting things on the page. Perhaps not always possible with dynamically generated stuff...)

Comment: @user1011471: Wow, I'm surprised it worked. I'm not very experienced with XPath; while my CSS selector answers are based on certain knowledge (as in "I know this stuff; I've studied it for years"), my XPath answers are little more than intelligent guesses :)