# Filter CSS selector based on child properties

Tags: css

Given that there are no [parent selectors in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/) and [even in Python one must resort to XML to get to parent elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330042/css-selector-based-on-parent-and-child-nodes), how might one target the `<li>` element which contains the `<span class="foo">` element?

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="bar">John</span></li>
    <li><span class="bar">Paul</span></li>
    <li><span class="foo">George</span></li>
    <li><span class="bar">Ringo</span></li>
</ul>
```

This is in CSS: no Javascript, jQuery, Selenium, or Ford Pantera in the environment.

Comment: You can't. One could only find ways to add specific class to its wrapper element like <li class="parent-of-foo"> or something like that

Comment: One will have to wait until CSS4’s `:has()` selector is implemented in browsers then.

Comment: How come there is no Javascript in the environment?

Comment: @Vucko: This is for a page description device, not for running in a web browser. Actually the CSS 4 implementation is viable for this because I'm the one coding the support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the moment, you can't.

CSS Selectors Level 4 has a new selector `:has`

[**MDN Reference `:has`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

> The :has() CSS pseudo-class represents an element if any of the selectors, relative to the:scope of the given element, passed as parameters, matches at least one element. The :has() pseudo-class takes a selector list as an argument.

In  your case it would be

```
`li:has(span.foo) {}`
```

At present though, no broswer supports this selector.

Comment: Even though the question wants pure CSS, it is worth noting that [jQuery does support :has in selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/).